# Should this be tagged [galois-theory]?

Tags: support, tagging, specific-question

I am not sure if I should add a tag for [galois-theory] (or [field-theory]?) on [How to describe the Galois group of the compositum of all quadratic extensions of Q?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1512/how-to-describe-the-galois-group-of-the-compositum-of-all-quadratic-extensions-of) and [How to solve a cyclic quintic in radicals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388/how-to-solve-a-cyclic-quintic-in-radicals) and [What is a primitive polynomial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1324/what-is-a-primitive-polynomial)

what do you think?

Comment: (I wonder why someone downvoted this post?..)

Comment: @Grigory: On meta.stackoverflow, at least, a downvote on a meta question is typically shorthand for "I disagree," because meta questions are often requests for particular administrator/moderator action. Here, I agree that it makes no sense, because there are 3 different questions.

Answer (score 1):

First one yes, second one no.